# How do I determine my current bounty?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Oblivion, one of the stats was your current bounty, which was a great way to double-check to make sure you weren't caught when stealing, etc. But Skyrim doesn't seem to have this.

I've found one proxy method: You can see your lifetime bounty in Stats/Crime. You have to keep your current amount memorized though, if you want to use it as a "did I just get caught" check.

Comment: +1 This is a great question. I'm having trouble figuring this one out too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On a console, press start -> stats tab -> 2nd or 3rd page down, it lists your exact bounties and in which cities  :)

My guess is that on the PC it would be <kbd>Esc</kbd> or something... it's there the first page is your quests, the second is "stats" and the third your saves.

Comment: Yay! Looks like they finally patched it so that it shows up in stats.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there is no direct "interface" way of finding out what your exact bounty is. This is most likely a design oversight.

Another trick to do it would be to save, let yourself get caught by a guard and see how much bounty you have to pay. Then reload.

Comment: We can hope for a Mod!

Comment: If you have a low bounty, you may be able to convice the guard that it's not worth his time. He'll let you go, and you'll still have the bounty, but you won't have to reload.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to see your current bounties. Go to:

```
Quest Menu > General Stats > System Screen
```

General stats, under crime, you can see your current bounties. If there are no cities shown up, it means you have no bounty. It's that simple. :)

Comment: This is true, folks. I just slaughtered a guard, and the new bounty showed up at the top of the normal Crime stats screen as “The Rift Bounty: 1000”.

Answer (score 3):

The system lists the bounty amount twice when you stole something or kill someone:

1. You get a warning message at the top of the screen, it lists the bounty amount.
2. Guards will hunt you down, they will ask you for the bounty amount (if not, they will try to kill you).

It's obvious when you got caught stealing or killing someone:

1. You will get the warning if they decided to put a bounty on you.
2. You will hear a dialog related to your stealing.
3. Persons will flee to get guards or attack you, guards will attack you.

I don't see why you would need to know the bounty if you don't have the chance anymore to pay it, as they are chasing you down. As for looking whether they detected you, the systems has enough ways of telling you so that you do not need to check if you have a bounty on your head.

Comment: Primarily to see which towns are hostile ~

Comment: @Domocus: Write it down on a note?

Comment: If gaurds are chasing you, all you need to do is attack one with your weapon then put it away to wield and a dialog to pay the bounty will appear.

Comment: Also, a high bounty can be a point of pride. How can we bask in it if we can't just open the journal and see it?

Comment: Bounty is not always related to stealing. I generally find myself wanting to check it when I'm in the wilderness (no guards around to indicate my criminal status with their actions) and I've just finished a fight (enough other stuff going on that I haven't been watching for messages in the top left) and suspect that I may have committed assault against a non-hostile participant in the combat. None of the indicators you mentioned are reliably helpful in that situation.

Comment: Because you shouldn't be caring about bounties at that point, if you have one and are close they'll chase... :)